# Truffle Migrate Not Deploying After second migration

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm trying to test gas expenditures of different types and implementations of common contracts (e.g. OpenZeppelin).

I am using Truffle migrate to deploy these contracts, and have an instance of ganache-cli mainnet fork running in the background on local host, forked from an Infura node.

When I first spin up the ganache instance, then go on truffle console to migrate - everything works fine. It compiles, then deploys, and I am able to see how much gas was used, block timestamp, etc.

However, when I add another solidity file (representing another contract to test) to the contracts folder or replace the old one with a new contract, then do truffle migrate, it only compiles it. I read that truffle migrate sees that the network is up-to-date and does not update. Ok, fine.

So I try deleting the build folder, and hit migrate --reset. Same thing, no deployment.

When I reset the ganache-cli fork and also restart truffle console (coupled with deleting the build folder), now it works and I am able to see the transaction information that I need from the deployment. But it's more tedious than it needs to be, and I think I'm missing something here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Am I overlooking a truffle command or migrate option? Do I need to change my initial migration js file? It looks like this:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

The contract migration files are pretty much the same except with the smart contract info:

```
const GameItems = artifacts.require("GameItems");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(GameItems);
};
```

Migrations.sol is the one that comes with truffle init:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner = msg.sender;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "This function is restricted to the contract's owner"
    );
    _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
```

This is what my truffle-config.js file looks like:

```
/**
 * Use this file to configure your truffle project. It's seeded with some
 * common settings for different networks and features like migrations,
 * compilation and testing. Uncomment the ones you need or modify
 * them to suit your project as necessary.
 *
 * More information about configuration can be found at:
 *
 * trufflesuite.com/docs/advanced/configuration
 *
 * To deploy via Infura you'll need a wallet provider (like @truffle/hdwallet-provider)
 * to sign your transactions before they're sent to a remote public node. Infura accounts
 * are available for free at: infura.io/register.
 *
 * You'll also need a mnemonic - the twelve word phrase the wallet uses to generate
 * public/private key pairs. If you're publishing your code to GitHub make sure you load this
 * phrase from a file you've .gitignored so it doesn't accidentally become public.
 *
 */

const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
// const infuraKey = "....";
//
// const fs = require('fs');
// const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
   * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
   * will spin up a development blockchain for you on port 9545 when you
   * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
   * network from the command line, e.g
   *
   * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
   */

  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache-cli, geth or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*", // Any network (default: none)
    },
    // Another network with more advanced options...
    // advanced: {
    // port: 8777,             // Custom port
    // network_id: 1342,       // Custom network
    // gas: 8500000,           // Gas sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
    // gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
    // from: <address>,        // Account to send txs from (default: accounts[0])
    // websocket: true        // Enable EventEmitter interface for web3 (default: false)
    // },
    // Useful for deploying to a public network.
    // NB: It's important to wrap the provider as a function.
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          "",
          `api end piont`
        ),
      network_id: 4, // Rinkeby's id
      gas: 5500000, // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      confirmations: 2, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200, // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true, // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },
    // mainnet: {
    //   provider: () =>
    //     new HDWalletProvider(
    //       "",
    //       "
    //     ),
    //   network_id: 1, // mainnet
    //   gas: 5500000,
    //   gasPrice: 2000000000, // check https://ethgasstation.info/
    //   confirmations: 2, // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
    //   timeoutBlocks: 200, // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
    //   skipDryRun: false, // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    // },
    // Useful for private networks
    // private: {
    // provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://network.io`),
    // network_id: 2111,   // This network is yours, in the cloud.
    // production: true    // Treats this network as if it was a public net. (default: false)
    // }
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.7", // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    },
  },
  plugins: ["truffle-plugin-verify"],
  api_keys: {
    etherscan: "",
  },

  // Truffle DB is currently disabled by default; to enable it, change enabled: false to enabled: true
  //
  // Note: if you migrated your contracts prior to enabling this field in your Truffle project and want
  // those previously migrated contracts available in the .db directory, you will need to run the following:
  // $ truffle migrate --reset --compile-all

  db: {
    enabled: false,
  },
};
```

Much appreciation in advance.